# Hello, this showed up on my math test and it has everybody confused, could someone solve it ? |z-1|>|z-i|

Tags: complex-numbers

So the question is :

Solve and draw

|z-1|>|z-i|

When z= x + iy

I got to -1/2 > (x^2) + (y^2)  - This is probably wrong

Thank you

Comment: You are given two points and asked from where the distance is lesser to the first point than to the second one.

Comment: Perhaps you'd find it easier to find those $z\in \mathbb C$ with $|z-i|=|z-1|$

Comment: Will you show how you got your answer?

Comment: What is the set of points where the two distances are equal? (Hint: it's a line.)

Comment: Note:  your expression doesn't make sense.  There are no real $x,y$ for which $-\frac 12>x^2+y^2$.

Comment: @lulu In the answer i got to the answer is the area above the point the square root of -1/2 but ill stress it again, this is probably wrong.

Comment: A general comment: questions like this one about the complex numbers are often better settled (at least at first) by looking at the geometry rather than the algebra, as in the answer from @RossMillikan

Answer (score 2):

The geometric approach is in the figure below.  Point $A$ is $1$, point $B$ is $i$.  The line is the set of points equidistant from the two so for your greater than sign you want the open half-plane above the line.
[image]